# Reduce app size

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I'm using `Xcode` Version 7.3.1. My app contains just one `UIWebView` and 2 app icons, Project folder approximately take about `150 kb` storage. But when test it on real device(`iPhone 5`), and i check its size from Storage Manager in General setting, app take 16.2 mb?
`iOS` `Safari` just taking about 2mb. Why my app taking more `storage`? 
Any one have any idea how i can reduce its size??
Thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        webView.delegate = self
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com/")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: When the app is compiled on your machine, it can contain multiple (like 3 or 4) copies of compiled code for different hardware. When you deploy to Apple store, only the 1 copy that is needed is retained at install time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what you have in your project that takes up that much space, if you want to inspect your app you can generate an .ipa file and then:

> Simply change the extension of an .ipa file to .zip, then open it with
>   Finder to decompress it. Right-click on the unzipped .app bundle
>   and choose "Show Package Contents" to see the resources inside. This
>   can give you an idea of what is using the most space.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html).

But do note that an application that is in development is larger than the version you will put on App Store. It will at least decrease with 50-75% of size.